# Is it allowed to temporarily install Exchange 2010 when upgrading from 2003 to 2013?

Tags: exchange, licensing, upgrade, exchange-2013

As most of you know, there is no upgrade path from Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2013. Is it allowed with MS licensing to temporarily install 2010 so that I can then upgrade to 2013 even if they only bought Exchange 2013?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Buy purchasing the 2013 license you have downgrade rights to install older versions.  This would allow you to install 2010 (you have to find a copy of it yourself) so you can do the upgrade process.

Comment: Excellent. We have 2010 media so this is perfect. Thanks for the answer.